# Why is this POD initialised with 0?

Tags: c++, goto

I was trying learn behaviour of POD in case of goto. Following is the program I used:

```
#include <iostream>
void f(int i){
    if (i < 10)
         goto jump1;
    int j;
    jump1:
         std::cout << j;
}

int main()
{
    f(9);
}
```

Why is `j` initialised with 0?

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing to initialize a local non-static variable to zero in the standard, it's just a custom/random behaviour of you compiler.Reading a value from uninitialized variable can invoke an undefined behaviour. The `goto` has nothing to do with that declaration.

Comment: I was expecting a garbage value in j. And this undefined behaviour of my compiler cost me 3 downvotes.

Comment: For me that zero which comes from an uninitialized variable is garbage!

Comment: Undefined behavior can mean the value is garbage, the value is 0 or the compiler can simply remove all operations depending on that variable, or can make demons fly out of your nose.

Answer (score 1):

The `goto` jump itself is fine. By [stmt.dcl]/3:

> It is possible to transfer into a block, but not in a way that bypasses declarations with initialization. A program that jumps from a point where a variable with automatic storage duration is not in scope to a point where it is in scope is ill-formed unless the variable has scalar type [...] and is declared without an initializer (8.5).

However, what is *not* legal is to read an uninitialized variable by [dcl.init], and thus your program has undefined behaviour at runtime if you call `f` with an argument less than 10.